# Internet Explorer 9 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Why doesn't this code work in Internet Explorer 9?

```
function calc() {
  alert('aaa');
}
$('body').delegate('input', 'change', function(){
  // In here, $(this) is the input that has changed
  calc();
});
$('body').delegate('select', 'change', function(){
  calc();
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Error messages?

Comment: What are you expecting, and what are you experiencing?

Comment: nothing add- it work in ff and chrome, none ie9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, change event doesn't bubble up in IE. `$.delegate` only works for events that bubble. Are you saying this works for earlier versions of IE?

Comment: i tested in ff\chrome, now boss say that ie not work, so i look for solution

Comment: Boss shouldn't have to tell you that it's broken in IE :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/ This says that change should bubble (even in IE) for jquery 1.4 and newer, check your jquery version

Comment: i use <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: Yet `change` is conspicuously absent from the docs for `live()`. It does reference a bunch of specific event types, and: *"...as well as all JavaScript events that bubble"*. Since live/delegate use event delegation, it would seem as though they would rely on the *browser's* ability to bubble the event instead of a manufactured bubbling.

Comment: delegate does work for change in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/FeehP/ Maybe there's a bug with jquery's workaround that makes change bubble in IE that's not good enough to work in IE9

Comment: @Juan: Interesting. I suppose their workaround relies on a `focus/blur` type of event (or something).

Comment: @kusanagi: We just broke down what the problem is, you need to do some work yourself now, or just wait for someone else, not very polite to just ask "give me work example"

Answer (score 0):

Are you ensuring that your JQuery calls are in the DOMReady event:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate("input, select", "change", function() {
        calc();
    }
});
```